# .NET using multiple provider SSO, How can I determine which authentication method is being used?

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, accountmanager

I have a .NET application that uses many different authentication methods including `NTLM` and `SAML`. Inside my `ExternalLoginCallback` I need to determine which method is being used and I am currently doing this by taking the `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` and checking the `Login.LoginProvider`.

I want to know if the authentication method is `SAML` so I see if the `Login.LoginProvider` contains a word in a list like `["KentorAuthServices", "shibboleth", "saml", "stubidp", "metadata"]` but I don't want to update this list every time I find a new login provider for `SAML`.

I know there has to be a better way to do this but I'm a newbie at SAML at the moment.

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!